# AS3 - Issues with functions of instances

Tags: actionscript-3, instance

I have three classes that I am using and have shortened for ease of reading, leaving out the package and imports. `MainClass` is my document class, `Player` is a class linked to a movieclip, and `KeyHandler` is a class i'm using to contain the functions for my key presses. First, the code..

```
public class  TestMain extends Sprite
{
    public var keyHandler:KeyHandler = new KeyHandler();
    public var timer:Timer = new Timer(30);
    public var player:Player = new Player();

    public function TestMain()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler.KeyPress);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler.KeyRelease);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
        timer.start();

        stage.addChild(player);
    }

    public function onTick(timerEvent:TimerEvent)
    {
        player.Move();
    }
}
```

Player Class..

```
public class Player extends Sprite
{
    public var keyHandler:KeyHandler = new KeyHandler();

    public function Player()
    {
    }

    public function Move():void
    {
        trace("this works");
        if (keyHandler.upKeyIsPressed)
        {
            trace("this doesnt work")
        }
    }

}
```

KeyHandler class..

```
public class KeyHandler extends Sprite
{
    public var upKeyIsPressed:Boolean = false;

    public function KeyHandler() 
    {
    }

    public function KeyPress(keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            upKeyIsPressed = true;
        }
    }

    public function KeyRelease(keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            upKeyIsPressed = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Holding down the up key doesn't trace anything, but the `Move` function does. Should I make `KeyHandler` static, or is there an easy fix? Is this bad practice to do?

Comment: What if you changed the `keyHandler`'s to `KeyHandler`'s? Instead of making a keyHandler (with lowercase 'k') var? Like `stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyHandler.KeyPress);` ..Does that work?

Comment: The problem is the keyHandler isn't the same instance between the Player class and the TestMain class.  Two options basically, either create an instance and pass it through to all the objects that need a handle on the instance of KeyHandler or make KeyHandler a singleton. http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_singletons.html

Comment: Oh wow, I hardly noticed that. I got an error when changing it to `KeyHandler`, because the functions aren't static, but I fixed the problem by changing it to `player.keyHandler.KeyPress`. Thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is option 1 from my comment

TestMain

```
public class  TestMain extends Sprite
{
    public var keyHandler:KeyHandler = new KeyHandler();
    public var timer:Timer = new Timer(30);
    public var player:Player = new Player();

    public function TestMain()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler.KeyPress);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler.KeyRelease);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
        timer.start();
        player.keyHandler = keyHandler;
        stage.addChild(player);
    }

    public function onTick(timerEvent:TimerEvent)
    {
        player.Move();
    }
}
```

Player

```
public class Player extends Sprite
{
    public var keyHandler:KeyHandler;

    public function Player()
    {
    }

    public function Move():void
    {
        trace("this works");
        if (keyHandler.upKeyIsPressed)
        {
            trace("this should be working now")
        }
    }

}
```

KeyHandler

```
public class KeyHandler extends Sprite
{
    public var upKeyIsPressed:Boolean = false;

    public function KeyHandler() 
    {
    }

    public function KeyPress(keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            upKeyIsPressed = true;
        }
    }

    public function KeyRelease(keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            upKeyIsPressed = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Option 2 is making a "Singleton" type of setup where you get an instance of the class through a static method.  Only one instance of the class is used throughout in this case and doesn't require passing the instance through objects that don't actually need a handle on it themselves.  In the link in my comment on the OP I there's discussion on options for enforcing the pattern so no new instances are accidentally made, I'm just using the simple option here that causes a runtime error:

```
public class KeyHandler extends Sprite
{
    public var upKeyIsPressed:Boolean = false;
    public static var SINGLETON:KeyHandler = new KeyHandler();
    public static function getInstance():KeyHandler
    {
        return SINGLETON;
    }

    public function KeyHandler() 
    {
        if(SINGLETON)
            throw new Error("There can be only one!!!");
    }

    public function KeyPress(keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            upKeyIsPressed = true;
        }
    }

    public function KeyRelease(keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            upKeyIsPressed = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Player

```
public class Player extends Sprite
{
    public var keyHandler:KeyHandler = KeyHandler.getInstance();

    public function Player()
    {
    }

    public function Move():void
    {
        trace("this works");
        if (keyHandler.upKeyIsPressed)
        {
            trace("this should be working now")
        }
    }

}
```

TestMain

```
public class  TestMain extends Sprite
{
    public var keyHandler:KeyHandler = KeyHandler.getInstance();
    public var timer:Timer = new Timer(30);
    public var player:Player = new Player();

    public function TestMain()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler.KeyPress);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler.KeyRelease);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
        timer.start();
        player.keyHandler = keyHandler;
        stage.addChild(player);
    }

    public function onTick(timerEvent:TimerEvent)
    {
        player.Move();
    }
}
```

Here's another way to enforce the Singleton that will cause compile time errors so you see the problem earlier on:

http://blog.pixelbreaker.com/actionscript-3-0/as30-better-singletons